# Viewing Timeout Values in AWS Elastic Beanstalk for a Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Spring Boot application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Is an API available that would allow me to view all of the timeout values set in the environment, similar to how I can expose the application’s environment set values using `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include`
?